# Doctrine2 + Symfony2: Can Doctrine just map properties using direct access?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to use Doctrine2 for ORM. I have a very simple class and an XML metadata mapping.

The general idea is that the communication via ORM and class should happen via get/set methods only, without exposing internals of the class (e.g. private property names) to the orm.

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Entity;

class Test {

    private $name_property = null;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name_property = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name_property;
    }

}
```

And the mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

<entity name="Foo\Bar\Entity\Test">
    <field name="Name" type="text" />
</entity>
```

I thought this setup should call the methods getName() and setName($string_argument) when un-/serializing the object from/to database.

Obviously it doesn't.

```
Property Foo\Bar\Entity\Test::$Name does not exist
```

I thought Doctrine2 always uses get/set Methods to interact with the object, because the but it tries to access the property directly.

Can Doctrine really just map class field properties and always tries to access them directly? What if my set() methods contain business logic (e.g. string parameter validation) so setting the property directly via Doctrine2 is not an option? I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Property Foo\Bar\Entity\Test::$Name does not exist

$name is never declared in your Test class. And trying to access $name_property will not be possible from outside, since it's declared as private. And you don't need it either. For that reason are the Set and Get methods there.

> Can Doctrine really just map class field properties and always tries
>   to access them directly? What if my set() methods contain business
>   logic

I think that is a wise idea to leave the Doctrine Models with their setters and getters as you have posted. 
Leave the business logic in your own class out of the ORM. The mission of the ORM is to be the database abstraction layer between your code and the DB, so you can do all the operations using OOP.

In the symfony docs this is described better: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
And in the best practices book, chapter 4, you can read "Organizing your business logic":
http://symfony.com/doc/download-best-practices-book/